# Directive that replaces its element and puts another directive on the new element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

For learning purposes I want to create a directive that transforms this markup:

```
<my-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" href="{{tab.href}}">{{tab.title}}</tab>
```

Into this:

```
<li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-class="tabClass('{{tab.href}}')"><a ng-href="{{tab.href}}">{{tab.title}}</a></li>
```

How would you do this?

I tried to use `replace` in the directive definition but it puts `href` attribute from the `<my-tab>` on the `<li>` element and it is not what I want. Besides it is marked as deprecated.

Replacing the `<my-tab>` directive element with `<li>` in `compile` function does not help too. It produces the markup I want but `ng-class` does not work. My guess it is bacause the replacing element is not rescanned for directives on it.

Comment: Why do you want to change the markup?  Angular is there for you to augment, so you would go:
    <li my-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-class="tabClass('{{tab.href}}')"><a ng-href="{{tab.href}}">{{tab.title}}</a></li>, and the directive would just do what you want on the li element.

Comment: @frandroid, sorry. I can't quite understand the question. I am now learning Angular and want to understand how directives work. I had an idea to write two directives <my-tabset> (container) and <my-tab> (for individual tab) that detect route changes and updates active tab style accordingly.

Comment: I see you edition now. The idea was to make mark up a little bit cleaner. For instance tabClass would be an internal method not visible to user, no need to repeat <li>s and <a>s etc.